# A method triggers a console.log from another component

Tags: reactjs

When I click on bet now the function triggers a console.log from another component. betNow should group all the inputs from stake in one common array but when I click on it it renders the console log from stake and includes all the values that I typed into one array. Everything works but not as I wish. The parent component should display the common array with all the values. I do not understand why it is happening.Could anyone explain me why is reacting like that? Thanks in advance

Parent Component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import FilterMenu from "./selectButton";
import FetchRandomBet from "./fetchRandomBets";

function Betslip() {
    const data = [
        {
            value: 0,
            label: "No Filter"
        },
        {
            value: 1,
            label: "Less than two"
        },
        {
            value: 2,
            label: "More than two"
        },
    ]

    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(0);
    const [allStakes, setAllStakes] = useState([]);

    const handleChange = obj => {
        setSelectedValue(obj.value);
    }

    const betNow = () => {
        const stakes = localStorage.getItem("stakes");
        const jsnStake = JSON.parse(stakes) || [];
        setAllStakes([...allStakes, jsnStake]);
    }

    return (
        <div className="betslip">
            <div className="betslip-top">
                <h1 className="text">BETSLIP</h1>
                <p className="text-two">BET WITH US!</p>
                <div>
                    <FilterMenu
                        optionsProp={data}
                        valueProp={selectedValue}
                        onChangeProp={handleChange}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <FetchRandomBet
                    valueProp={selectedValue}
                />
            </div>
            <Button
                onClick={betNow}
                className="betnow"
                variant="contained"
            >
                Bet Now!
                </Button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Betslip;
```

Child Component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Stake() {
    const [stakes, setStakes] = useState([]);

    const addStake = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const newStake = e.target.stake.value;
        setStakes([newStake]);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const json = JSON.stringify(stakes);
        localStorage.setItem("stakes", json);
    }, [stakes]);
    console.log(stakes)
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={addStake}>
                <input
                    style={{
                        marginLeft: "40px",
                        width: "50px"
                    }}
                    type="text"
                    name="stake"
                    required
                />
            </form>

        </div>
    );
}

export default Stake;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this console.log in you function that will run every time the component is rendered, since it´s outside of any function:

[image]